# AngularJS directives accessing the same scope object - avoid overwrite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to wrap an angular object into a template which I should then be able to instantiate by using a directive. In this case each directive is a type of widget.

The problem comes from the fact that the directives I am writing are based on the same type, so when instantiating a directive I am keeping a track of the widget object in the global scope. I have something in the lines of:

```
.directive('lineChart', ['$interval', '$compile', 'widgetDataService',
    return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            templateUrl: 'templates/lineChart.html',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                var obj = {
                    guid: attrs['guid'],
                    datasource: undefined
                }

                scope.widgets.push(obj)
...
```

So then in the template I can do:

```
...
k-data-source="widgets[{{index}}].datasource"
...
```

The idea here being that consequent uses of the directive would result in sequentially initialised templates - and therefore each template would get its respective index. However this doesn't work. If I use a directive more than once all instantiated templates get the last index, which probably means that angular is separating the instantion in different stages.

Is there a way to use a global object to keep track of the underlying objects of the directives, but still let them have different indexes passed in at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and set a variable in the factory function of the directive (as this is only called once) and then increment it during the link phase:

```
.directive('lineChart', ['$interval', '$compile', 'widgetDataService',
  function($interval, $compile, widgetDataService) {
    var index = 0;  //initialize index
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/lineChart.html',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            var currentIndex = index++;  //increment on linking
            scope.index = currentIndex;
            var obj = {
                guid: attrs['guid'],
                datasource: undefined
            }

            scope.$parent.widgets[currentIndex] = obj;

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
               index--;
            });
...
```

In the view:

```
k-data-source="$parent.widgets[{{index}}].datasource"
```

Comment: Using `widgets[{{$$index}}].datasource` produces an $parse error. [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%5D&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=9&p3=widgets%5B%5D.datasource&p4=%5D.datasource) 
Why the double $-sign?

Comment: It produces a parse error because ` $$index ` does not resolve to anything. I've double chacked my code. It should be correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should only be `$index`. I was thinking of `$$hashkey`.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work either. I'll be able to test again on Monday. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes - `{{$index}}` evals to an empty string. I am able to access the global index by doing `scope.index`, but not the one initialised in the directive. Any idea why?

Comment: Wait, you want to access the index initialized by the directive? That won't work. If you set the index in the parent scope (which you do by setting `scope: false`), each subsequent instantiation of the directive will overwrite it. I will edit my answer.